# How to make ajax success callback data available globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So i'have some data returned from a rails backend, and i would like to make those data available globally, i have read about windows.variable = success callback data but i have to set async:false on ajax request which is now deprecated and does not work.

Is there a new workaround on that?

here is my ajax code

```
function retrieve(date_partial) {

    var jsondata = {
      events: {
        month: date_partial,
      }
    }

    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: "POST",
      url: "/events/find",
      data: jsondata,
      success: function(data) {



        for (var i = 0; i < data.events.length; i++) {
          var day = data.events[i].date.substring(0, 2);
          $("td[data-day='" + day + "']").addClass('added');
        }

      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        alert("The error code is: " + xhr.statusText);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have read about windows.variable

That's exactly how you make a value available globally in JavaScript, setting it on the `window` object.  Something like this:

```
window.someVariable = someValue;
```

> but i have to set async:false on ajax request

You absolutely *should not* do that.  It also has nothing to do with what you're asking.  The `window` object is always available, that's what makes it global:

```
success: function(data) {
    window.someVariable = data.someValue;
}
```

Once the callback runs, `window.someVariable` would contain the value and would be available to any other code on the page.

Comment: when i made a console.log(on the window variable) i got undefined and i figure is because the ajax request is async, thus how can i know for sure when that variable has a value in it?

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou: It sounds like you were trying to log the variable to the console before it was available.  Though I can't really comment on code that isn't shown in the question.  How you'd know when the variable is set is basically after you've set it.  Whatever needs to happen after the variable is set would need to be invoked from the callback.  Or, a bit fancier, you could use something like an MVVM framework which binds to the value and would update the UI once the value is changed.

Comment: yes that was what i was doing heh. thank you your answer solved my question!